# TPM Key Authenticity and Verification

Tags: tpm

How can the authenticity of the keys stored in the TPM be verified to be authentic? How can the PK, KEK, db and dbx keys viewed by using the command "mokutil --'xx'" (in Ubuntu) be verified to be the keys in use for secure boot and the ones which are stored in the TPM?

Comment: Wait, are you asking about TPM keys or about Secure Boot keys? Those are completely different things – SB doesn't even use the TPM.

Comment: @grawity I'm trying to ask about the PK, KEK, db and dbx keys.  If I'm mistaken, I appologize, but I thought those were the keys stored in the TPM and used during secure boot.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about two completely different features:

- Secure Boot keys are stored as EFI variables. They are protected by the firmware in *some* way (such that it should be impossible to change the KEK without having the full private PK, or to change the db without having the KEK) – but they are not necessarily protected by the TPM. An implementation might use TPM-provided NVRAM or it might use some other tamper-proof NVRAM or it might be lazy and use general-purpose EFI variable NVRAM.
- The TPM stores general-purpose keys. It can seal data to the current *system state*, including a hash of various EFI variables. For example, changing the KEK or the db would alter the hashes written to TPM PCRs, and therefore make all PCR-locked data no longer accessible. (The same goes for changing the boot order, etc.) However, the TPM is a standalone chip (or a firmware feature) and does not rely on Secure Boot for its functions.
- The two features interact, but they do not depend on each other. Many systems with Secure Boot in fact do not even have a TPM. Likewise, many systems with TPMs do not have Secure Boot, and many do not even have UEFI at all. (Only TPM 2.0 requires UEFI; TPM 1.2 does not.)